# Custom Editor using kineticjs text underline

Tags: kineticjs

i am trying to buil an editor using kineticjs, which has some text styling. i am stuck at a point where i have to add text underline style. Is there any option to achieve this functionality?

like -

sample text

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no built-in option for underlining.**

KineticJS is built on html5 canvas and canvas has no text decoration for underlining.

The only workaround is to manually draw a line under the text

- create a group
- add Kinetic.Text to the group
- add Kinetic.Line to the group which is used to underline the text
- measure the width of the text
- make the width of the line as measured
- make the baselineY of the line as desired

Here is example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/r2ZsK/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var utilCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
    var utilCtx=utilCanvas.getContext("2d");

    createUnderlinedText("sample text",20,50,18,"verdana",19);

    function createUnderlinedText(text,x,y,fontsize,fontfamily,baselineY){

        if(!baselineY){ baselineY=fontsize+1; }

        utilCtx.font=fontsize+" "+fontfamily;
        var textWidth=utilCtx.measureText(text).width;

        var ulText=new Kinetic.Group({
            x:x,
            y:y,
            draggable:true,
        });
        layer.add(ulText);

        var text = new Kinetic.Text({
            x:0,
            y:0,
            text:"sample text",
            fontSize:fontsize,
            fontFamily:fontfamily,
            fill: 'black',
        });
        ulText.add(text);

        var ul=new Kinetic.Line({
            points:[0,baselineY,textWidth,baselineY],
            strokeWidth:1,
            stroke:"black"
        });
        ulText.add(ul);

        layer.draw();

    }

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Having said all of this and IMHO...If you need a text editor, there are lots of full-featured editors out there.  Choosing one of those is much easier than prodding html canvas to draw stylized text.